# nginx bad gateway error with two locations

Tags: nginx, nginx-reverse-proxy, nginx-location

I know there might be many questions that can be just like my question. So sorry for that. But I couldn't find any solution to my problem .I have two Flask Apps which are running on different docker containers.  Requests that going through container_1 are working well but for container_2 are not unfortunately.
Requests can't be passed to container_2 so far.

After sending request for container_2 ,for example:  https://my.api.com/admin/xxxx
then receiving 502 bad gateway error.

Here is ngnix access log :

```
[23/Sep/2021:22:05:55 +0000] "POST /admin/xxxx HTTP/1.1" 502 166 "-" "PostmanRuntime/7.28.4"
```

This is my configuration for two containers that mentioned above:

```
upstream container1_name {
    server local_ip_of_container_1:8029;
}
upstream container2_name {
    server local_ip_of_container_2:8035;
}


server {
    server_name my.api.com;

    access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log;

    error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log;

    location  /admin/ {
        proxy_pass    http://container2_name;
    }

    location / {
        proxy_pass         http://container1_name;
        proxy_redirect     off;
        proxy_set_header   Host $host;
        proxy_set_header   X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-Host $server_name;
    }

    error_page 497 301 =307 https://$host:$server_port$request_uri;

    listen [::]:443 ssl ipv6only=on; # managed by Certbot
    listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate /etc/path/to/key; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/path/to/key; # managed by Certbot
}
```

I appreciate any answer for my question . thanks in advance

Comment: try changing admin's proxy pass to `proxy_pass    http://container2_name/;` note the trailing slash

Comment: tried but not working